Cat witnesses murder, gets revenge
So I watched a movie or a TV show decades ago.  It could have been a movie or perhaps a Twilight Zone episode.  Anyway, I’m trying to find it.  I’ve been searching for years, but I can’t remember the title.  So, maybe someone can help.
It’s about a cat who witnesses a murder.  The killer seemingly seems to get away with it.  We are left wondering up until the end how the cat will get its revenge.  The only other part I can remember is that the killer was bathing with either a radio or television nearby.  The cat jumps and pushes the electronic device into the tub and electrocutes the killer and that’s how the cat got its revenge.
I don’t think it was a movie after all. Given the twist at the end, seems like it could be a Hitchcock Hour or Twilight Zone episode.
This may be from the 80’s or early 90’s I think.  
I don’t think it’s this movie: The Shadow of the Cat.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Hello and welcome!   Please edit into your question as many details as you can remember.   Thank you  :)

This is probably not it, but there is The Black Cat from 1981? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Cat_(1981_film)

Thanks for the suggestion. I don’t think it was a movie after all. Given the twist at the end, seems like it could be a Hitchcock Hour or Twilight Zone episode.  I’m certain it was a cat that pushed a radio into a hot tub in order to get revenge on the man who killed his wife.
